# OpenSSL.NET How to implement PKCS7?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, openssl

I am writing an application where I need to encrypt, sign and wrap some content into a PKCS7/CMS structure. I am using [OpenSSL.NET](http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net) for the task (Wrapper for .NET).

I don't have much yet, I have successfully encrypted some data but

```
RSA toServer = cert.Certificate.PublicKey.GetRSA();
RSA fromClient = cert.Certificate.PublicKey.GetRSA();

byte[] cipherText = toServer.PublicEncrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!"), RSA.Padding.PKCS1);                
byte[] plainText = fromClient.PrivateDecrypt(cipherText, RSA.Padding.PKCS1);
```

This works, it successfully encrypts and decrypts the data, but now I want to move further and implement PKCS7/CMS so that I have a standard format for my messages. I have found the below object that seem to point in the right direction but I fail to find some documentation on how to use it:

```
OpenSSL.X509.PKCS7 p7 = new OpenSSL.X509.PKCS7( ? );
```

Any suggestions or references to documentation are welcome.

Comment: Do you know how OpenSSL.Net implements, for example, `STACK_OF`? For example, `STACK_OF(X509) *certs`? Anyway, here's the OpenSSL's docs on [PKCS7_sign(3)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_sign.html) and [PKCS7_verify(3)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_verify.html). OpenSSL's docs kind of suck. You can see how `openssl pkcs7 ...` works by examining the source in `<openssl src dir>/apps/pkcs7.c`.

Comment: And here's a source file from OpenSSL.Net's PKCS #7 gear: [ManagedOpenSsl/X509/PKCS7.cs](https://github.com/clowwindy/OpenSSL.net/blob/master/ManagedOpenSsl/X509/PKCS7.cs). And it looks like `STACK_OF` is an `IntPtr`.

Comment: I am very thankful for the hints, I will look into this and see if I am able to decipher how to do this with OpenSSL.NET, I guess I need to use Core.Stack, have taken a look at the C APIs and they seem straightforward but I am still puzzled on how to proceed on the .NET wrapper :/

Comment: @www.jensolsson.se If you have found a solution can you share it? Thanks!