# How to use SMIME OpenSSL.NET encryption

Tags: c#, openssl

Client is using OpenSSL to encrypt large files (~1MB). He is using SMIME:

```
openssl.exe smime -encrypt -des3 -in "plaintestFile.txt" -out "encryptedFile.txt" "certificate.pem" >> "log_encrypt.txt"
```

Now i need to do same thing in C# app. I've found a .Net OpenSSL wrapper : https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net

So far i have this, load PEM certificate from file:

```
public static void getCert()
    {
        OpenSSL.X509.Configuration cfg = new OpenSSL.X509.Configuration(@"D:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\openssl.cnf");

        string rootcerts = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\cert.pem");

        BIO certbio = new BIO(rootcerts);
        OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate cert = new OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate(certbio);
    }
```

But i cant find how to use SMIME in this wrapper. Help ?

Comment: SMIME is effectively PKCS #7 (some hand waiving). The last time I checked there is a `PKCS7.cs` in OpenSSL.Net. So see questions like [OpenSSL.NET How to implement PKCS7?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22699564), [Sign file using .NET OpenSSL wrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21849460), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the **OpenSslSmime class** from the commercial product [OpenSSL Library for .NET](https://www.didisoft.com/openssl-net/):

```
DidiSoft.OpenSsl.Cms.OpenSslSmime smime = new DidiSoft.OpenSsl.Cms.OpenSslSmime();
smime.EncryptFile("plaintestFile.txt", "certificate.pem", @"encryptedFile.txt", CmsCipherAlgorithm.Des3);
```

Disclaimer: I work for DidiSoft